# PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, database-connection

Every time I run my rails 4.0 server, I get this output.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-06 23:56:36 -0500

PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
:
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:792:in `current_version'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:800:in `needs_migration?'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:379:in `check_pending!'
 activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:366:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1613334440513032208__call__callbacks'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
 better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
 better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
 better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
 quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
 thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
 thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
 thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
 thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
 eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
 thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
 thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
 bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm running Mavericks OS X 10.9 so I don't know if that's the problem. I've tried everything I could but nothing seems to work. I've uninstalled and install both postgres and the pg gem multiple times now.

This is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: metals-directory_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password: 
  template: template0
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: metals-directory_test
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password: 
  template: template0
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: metals-directory_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
  template: template0
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: metals-directory_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
  template: template0
  host: localhost

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Comment: try adding 'host: localhost' in your database.yml, got this from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10793186/919641

Comment: @trajan I did that already. I even used that thread when I first started researching for a solution. I've posted my database.yml file. You can take a look at it. Maybe it might help.

Comment: show your pg_hba.conf

Comment: have you taken a look at [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565708/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrade-to-osx-mavericks)

Comment: @Anchor I tried what it said and no luck.

Comment: @Pronix where do I find my pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Based on the error message, pg_hba.conf is not the problem. The error basically indicates that postgres is not running at all. Which leads to the question: how are you launching it? And when launched, what does it say on the screen and in the log?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777461/rails-postgres-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-pgconnecti

Comment: Don't forget to turn the postgres app on if you're using that.

Comment: You probably restarted your computer and forgot to launch the Postgres app.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me turn on the app @PavanKatepalli! Good call ;)

Comment: If you're here because of the OSX Security Update 2017-004 here's your answer: https://gist.github.com/giannisp/ebaca117ac9e44231421f04e7796d5ca

Comment: after upgrading to `postgresql 11` on `Ubuntu 19.04` make sure that your `postgresql` server is running on `127.0.0.1:5432` with `sudo ss -tunelp | grep 5432`. Start the server with either `sudo systemctl restart postgresql` or `sudo service restart postgresql`. 
I also had to purge and delete the whole database with `sudo apt purge postgresql` before installing postgresql 11

Comment: I tend to get this when I've run a brew upgrade that replaces the version of postgresql version my DB needs. I validate the error's source by checking that the end of my postgres.log has errors about about version number incompatibility and then reinstall the version number that the error says I need.

Answer (score 763, accepted):

It could be as simple as a stale **PID file**. It could be failing silently because your computer didn't complete the shutdown process completely which means **postgres** didn't delete the **PID** (process id) file.

The PID file is used by postgres to make sure only one instance of the server is running at a time. So when it goes to start again, it fails because there is already a **PID** file which tells **postgres** that another instance of the server was started (even though it isn't running, it just didn't get to shutdown and delete the PID).

1. To fix it remove/rename the PID file. Find the postgres data directory. On macOS using homebrew it is in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`,
   or `/usr/local/var/log/` other systems it might be `/usr/var/postgres/`. On M1, it might be `/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql`.
2. To make sure this is the problem, look at the log file (`server.log`). On the last lines you will see:

> FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
> HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 347) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?

3. If so, `rm postmaster.pid`
4. Restart your server. On a mac using launchctl (with homebrew) the following commands will restart the server.

   ```
   brew services restart postgresql
   ```

OR on older versions of **Brew**

```
    launchctl unload homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist  
    launchctl load -w homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: #2 is a great suggestion: "Check server.log". My error was actually caused by upgrading to Yosemite, the server log said: `FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory`. This answer helped me with that problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite-beta

Comment: I just upvoted this because it gave me enough to fix the problem scorched earth style. I uninstalled pg (`gem uninstall pg`), uninstalled postgres (`brew uninstall postgres`), then nuked the postgres folder which was lingering with a bunch of stale stuff it in (`rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres`). After a reboot `brew install postgres`, `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`, and `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`. I don't know how many other solutions I tried before getting this to work.

Comment: is the postmaster.opts file the same as the postmaster.pid file?

Comment: `vim /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` then type GG to go to the last line, look at it, and press :q to quit.

Comment: The log might show that `FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.1.
` where you need to select the old postgres version by using `brew switch postgres 9.3.0` like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/380607

Comment: @IAmNaN have you considered adding this as a separate answer? I'm going through it now, hoping it works.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have because it's buried below the fold now and hard to find. I added a separate answer now, and it uses brew services to simplify things.

Comment: Worked for Django too. For step 4, didn't need to run those `launchctl` commands, just restarted using `./manage.py runserver` again

Comment: For newer Brew users, the command for #4 is `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: Mac OS Sierra - I can't `locate` a server.log - is it now system.log?

Comment: May I know why I don't have a `server.log` file

Comment: For me (MAC, homebrew) the log file was `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`

Comment: For anyone on macOS that removed the `postmaster.pid` file, but it didn't resolve the issue, I had to open Activity Monitor and remove the `postgres` process from there. 
Removing the pid file meant that restarting postgres using homebrew wasn't actually shutting down the process itself.

Comment: I find myself here every time my power goes out hahahaha

Comment: I checked `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`and it appeared that I had wrong permissions on `/usr/local/var/postgres`. Changed it to `0700` and it worked

Comment: I have multiple postgres versions installed, so in my var folder I had to search for the specific postgres version and it's .pid file to remove it.

Comment: This worked great for me, just wanted to make one note, it does take some time for the server to boot up (~5-10 minutes) in my case, so be patient if you think it isn't working. You can check the status by viewing the contents of postmaster.pid (I used "cat postmaster.pid"), it will go through three different stages in the boot up process if I remember correctly (booting, starting, and finally ready). I was also able to use pg_isready to view the status and once it was accepting connections I was able to connect and boot my rails server again.

Comment: Combination worked for me: first `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` then brew services restart postgresql  (I also find myself here everytime my mac panics!)

Comment: On M1 the postmaster.pid is in `/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql` instead of `/usr/local/var/postgres/`. Otherwise, everything works fine!

Answer (score 58):

You would need to **restart the Postgresql Server**.

If you are using ubuntu you can restart **Postgresql** by following command

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Thank you 1000 times. I've just upgraded my ubuntu version and this fixed for me.

Comment: Althought the question does refer to OSX Mavericks, this slution is handy for Ubuntu installations when something quirky happen in migration or server startup.

Answer (score 33):

I have managed to solve the problem by following the Chris Slade's answer, but to restart the server, I had to use the following commands:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist

launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990539/restarting-postgres-on-mac) (pjammer's answer down at the bottom)

Answer (score 28):

1. Uninstall pg:

   ```
   gem uninstall pg
   ```
2. Uninstall postgres:

   ```
   brew uninstall postgres
   ```
3. Nuke the postgres folder which might be lingering with a bunch of stale stuff it in:

   ```
   rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
   ```
4. Reboot (maybe unnecessary)
5. Reinstall pg:

   ```
   brew install postgres
   ```
6. My comment in Chris Slade's answer starts pg the hard way, now I use brew services which has simplified my life in so many ways:

   ```
   brew install services
   ```
7. And start pg with it:

   ```
   brew services start postgresql
   ```
8. Reinstall the gem:

   ```
   gem install pg
   ```

And bobsyouruncle.

Comment: Be careful with this method... this is a scorched earth approach and will most likely destroy any local dbs you currently have.  Have a look at https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy where you might be able to do `lunchy stop postgres` followed by `lunchy start postgres`

Comment: on ubuntu I believe `sudo apt purge postgresql` or any other `postgresql` pachage should be enough and it will destroy everything.

Comment: I did this and now get the following error : postgresql_adapter.rb:709:in `rescue in connect': FATAL:  database "project3_development" does not exist (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError). What should I do ? I can actually see the database in rubymine.

Answer (score 27):

Do you have postgresql installed within your system? If not, then watch [Install postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/download/). After you successfully integrate **postgresql** into your system you can type something like that in your system terminal:

```
which psql
#=> /usr/bin/psql
```

After that you need to create a user and database in postgresql like this:

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

Then you can see the following within your terminal

```
postgres=#
```

Type there:

```
CREATE USER yourname WITH PASSWORD 'passwordhere';
CREATE DATABASE metals-directory_production  WITH OWNER yourname;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE metals-directory_production TO yourname;
```

After you do this, then you need to correct your `database.yml`. Probably you need something like that:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: metals-directory_development
  pool: 5
  username: yourname
  password: passwordhere   ### password you have specified within psql
  host: localhost
  port: 5432               ### you can configure it in file postgresql.conf
```

Also if you have problems with postgresql it is good idea to check [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: I have it installed but the location is at     /usr/local/bin/psql and when I run    sudo -u postgres it says    sudo: unknown user: postgres

Comment: psql should work if you want to use pg in your app. Try type in terminal psql metals-directory_development. Any results? If not, then try to reinstall postgres [try this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686526/mountain-lion-postgres-could-not-connect/11688953#11688953)

Comment: When I run psql metals-directory_development I get psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I'm a beginner rails programmer and I have no idea what that means. I've tried reinstalling postgres numerous times but no luck.

Answer (score 22):

To fix these type of issues with **Postgres** and to work with **Postgres** on `Mac OSX`, this is probably the ***BEST*** and the ***EASIEST*** solution that I have found so far:

http://postgresapp.com/

Just download, install and be happy :)

Answer (score 17):

check the file **postgresql.conf** (on `ubuntu` is in **/etc/postgresql/X.X/main/postgresql.conf** ) and look for the line that says:

```
listen_addresses="localhost"
```

try change it to:

```
listen_addresses="*"
```

it would be accepting every IP's, next check the line that says:

```
port=5432
```

and check if is the same port of your database.yml, by default on my postgresql-9.2 use **5433** instead **5432**, don't forget to **restart** the postgres server,

*Good Luck!*

Comment: This was my problem as well.  I suspect it happened because I already had 9.3 running when I tried to "upgrade" (i.e. install 9.5).  I'm guessing it was trying to be polite and configure itself to run in parallel on a different port rather than take over the existing install/process.

Answer (score 14):

As described by @Magne, the error `PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused` can be presented following a [major/minor version](http://semver.org/) upgrade (e.g. `9.5 -> 9.6` or `9 -> 10`) of PostgreSQL.

I got this error after having run `brew upgrade postgresql` after the release of PostgreSQL version 9.6. The problem is that major/minor version upgrades require additional steps to migrate old date to the new version.

**How to check if this is your problem**

You can check if this is the problem by checking the latest brew formula PostgreSQL version installed with homebrew...

```
$ brew info postgresql

/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4_1 (3,147 files, 35M)
Poured from bottle on 2016-10-14 at 13:33:28
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1 (3,242 files, 36.4M) *
Poured from bottle on 2017-02-06 at 12:41:00
```

...and then comparing it to the current PG_VERSION

```
$ cat /usr/local/var/postgres/PG_VERSION
9.5
```

If the PG_VERSION is less than the latest brew formula and the difference is a major/minor version change, then this is probably your problem.

**How to fix (i.e. how to upgrade the data)**

*Instructions below are for an upgrade from 9.5 to 9.6. Change the version numbers as appropriate for your own upgrade*

***Step 1.*** Make sure PostgreSQL is switched off:

```
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
# or, with Homebrew...
$ brew services stop postgresql
```

***Step 2.*** Make a new pristine database:

```
$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.6 -E utf8
```

***Step 3.*** Check what the old and new binary versions are:

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/
9.5.3   9.5.4   9.6.1
```

Note that in this example I am upgrading from 9.5.4 binary to 9.6.1 binary

***Step 4.*** Migrate the current data to the new database using the [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html) utility.

```
$ pg_upgrade \
  -d /usr/local/var/postgres \
  -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.6 \
  -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4/bin/ \
  -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/ \
  -v
```

- `-d` flag specifies the current data directory
- `-D` flag specifies the new data directory to be created
- `-b` specifies the old binary
- `-B` specifies the new binary we're upgrading to

***Step 5.*** Move the old data directory out of the way

```
$ mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres9.5
```

***Step 6.*** Move newly created data directory to where PostgreSQL expects it to be

```
$ mv /usr/local/var/postgres9.6 /usr/local/var/postgres
```

***Step 7.*** Start PostgreSQL again

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
# or, if you're running a current version of Homebrew
$ brew services start postgresql
```

***Step 8.*** If you’re using the pg gem for Rails, you should recompile by uninstalling and reinstalling the gem (skip this step if you're not using the pg gem)

```
$ gem uninstall pg
$ gem install pg
```

***Step 9.(optional)*** After you've reassured yourself that everything is working OK, you can run regain some disk space with the following command:

```
brew cleanup postgresql
```

...and if you're feeling really brave you can delete the old PostgreSQL data directory with the following command

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres9.5/
```

*(This answer is based on an excellent blog post https://keita.blog/2016/01/09/homebrew-and-postgresql-9-5/ with some additions)*

Answer (score 13):

I got the same problem after updating my mac on Osx Movaje.

i found this solution :

Try first the bellow command line in your terminal :

```html
brew services restart postgresql
```

If nothing change :

```html
ps aux | grep postgres
```

If still nothing change :

```
ls -ls | grep post
```

Last command to fix it, removed the postgres lock file by executing from root :

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

and then :

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

From berziiii : https://github.com/ga-wdi-boston/capstone-project/issues/325

Hope that will help :)

Regards !!

Answer (score 8):

This is what really helped me.

```
$ cd /usr/local/var/postgres/
$ rm postmaster.pid
```

Reference:
http://alumni.lewagon.org/questions/60

Answer (score 7):

As suggested above, I just opened up the **Postgres App** on my Mac, clicked Open `Psql`, closed the `psql` window, restarted my **rails server** in my terminal, and it was working again, no more error.

Trust the elephant: http://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 7):

Locate your postgres file it could be in `/usr/local/var/postgres/` or in  `/usr/var/postgres/` and then delete the `postmaster.pid` file present in that folder.

Answer (score 5):

put `host: localhost` in `database.yml` file and run this command:

```
rake db:create db:migrate
```

Answer (score 5):

If you hit this problem after doing a `brew upgrade` which upgraded postgres to a new major version (f.ex `9.3.0` to `9.4.0` or higher), then do this:

> @dmitrygusev's fix from https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35240
>
> Following official [Postgresql] migration guide helped:
>
> ```
> brew switch postgres 9.3.5    # presuming you already installed 9.4.1
> pg_dumpall > outputfile
> launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
> mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres.old
> brew switch postgres 9.4.1
> initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres
> psql -d postgres -f outputfile
> ```
>
> That's all. Check if import went well, then delete backups:
>
> ```
> rm outputfile
> rm -Rf /usr/local/var/postgres.old
> ```

The issue here is that on a major version upgrade of postgres, it's necessary to recreate/migrate your database. And possibly `chown` directories or manually call `initdb`.

See also: [How to upgrade PostgreSQL from version 9.6 to version 10.1 without losing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379373/how-to-upgrade-postgres-from-9-3-to-9-4-without-losing-data)

---

Some other tips, that might come in handy, in case you're not using Homebrew:

Stop PG server manually:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log stop`

Start PG server manually:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

Answer (score 4):

This occurred for me after upgrade Postgres (through Homebrew). I upgraded from version 12 to 13.

If this is the case for you try running `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` and check the output. In my case it stated `database files are incompatible with server`.

You might get an error message that postgres.old already exists

```
Error: /usr/local/var/postgres.old already exists!
```

To fix that, just remove that file

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres.old
```

Fixing the database was as simple as running:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Answer (score 3):

If removing `postmaster.pid` does not resolve the issue, this worked for me:

```
cd /usr/local/var/
rm -rf postgres/
mkdir postgres
initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 postgres/
brew services restart postgresql
```

Credit to @spirito_libero 's solution on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6612534/spirito-libero).

Comment: This worked but I lost all of my local databases

Answer (score 2):

Mac users with the Postgres app may want to open the application (spotlight search Postgres or find the elephant icon in your menu bar). Therein you may see a red X with the message: "Stale postmaster.pid file". Unfortunately a spotlight search won't show the location of this file. Click "Server Settings...", and in the dialog box that opens, click the "Show" button to open the Data Directory. Navigate one folder in (for me it was "var-10"), and delete the `postmaster.pid` file.

Go back to the Postgres app and click the Start button. That red X should turn into a green check mark with the message "Running". Now you should be able to successfully run Rails commands like `rails server` in the terminal.

[image: Postgres App Server Settings - Show Data Directory]

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks so much for the solution! It was a process!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem tonight, working on a rails application I've been working on for a while. My problem simply came down to the fact that **my postgresql server was not running**.

I went to the top of the screen (I'm on a Mac) and clicked the little elephant icon and clicked 'Start'.

Turns our the server wasn't on.

Hopefully this provides a simple solution for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all of the answers above and it didn't work for me.

In my case when I chekced the log on `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`. It was fine no error. But I could see that it was listening my local IPV6 address which is `"::1"`

In my `database.yml` It was like this

```
host:     <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_ADDON_HOST'] || '127.0.0.1' %>
```

I changed it by

```
host:     <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_ADDON_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
```

and then it worked

Comment: I did the opposite, changed from localhost to 127.0.0.1 and worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this explanation solved it for me: http://blog.55minutes.com/2013/09/postgresql-93-brew-upgrade/

key step was looking at the tail of my **/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log** , 
that let me see what the real problem was, which was that i hadn't fully completed the process of upgrading PostgreSQL

Comment: Similar situation here -- the key for me also was to look at `server.log`.  Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Slade's answer helped me.

I wrote a little script to kill those remaining processes if usefull:

```
kill_postgres() {
  if [[ $* -eq "" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: 'kill_postgres <db_name>' to kill remaining instances (Eg. 'kill_postgres my_app_development')"
  else
    gksudo echo "Granted sudo"
    pids="$(ps xa | grep postgres | grep $* | awk '{print $1}' | xargs)"
    if [[ $pids -eq "" ]]; then
      echo "Nothing to kill"
    else
      for pid in "${pids[@]}"
      do
        echo "Killing ${pid}"
        sudo kill $pid
        echo "Killed ${pid}"
      done
      kill_postgres $*
    fi
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in my **application.yml** file.  My database `url` on `heroku` was not using port 5342.  Check your `heroku` config `var DATABASE_URL`.  Make sure that matches exactly with was in your **application.yml** for the applicable database.

Answer (score 1):

I just run this command `sudo service postgresql restart`
and everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in production (development everything worked), 
in my case the DB server is **not** on the same machine as the app, so finally what worked is just to migrate by writing:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

and then restart the server and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but might help somebody.
I was having the same issue. Turns out that I'd two versions of postgres 9.1 and 9.5. I uninstalled 9.1 and 9.5 and installed 9.5 again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I Check the last line of `PostgreSQL` log files in `/var/log/postgresql`.
There was an unrecognized configuration parameter in file **/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf**. Commenting the error line in `postgresql.conf` resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Homebrew package manager includes launchctl plists to start automatically. For more information run `brew info postgres`.

Start manually:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

Stop manually:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop`

Start automatically:

"To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:"

`brew services start postgresql`

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was permissions issue.

When I see logs I found out the issue, Run

```
cat /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

I found out

```
2020-07-17 15:08:47.495 PKT [16282] FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has invalid permissions
2020-07-17 15:08:47.495 PKT [16282] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
```

I just ran

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /usr/local/var/postgres
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the rails server, ran `rake db:migrate` and started my `rails s`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error after following a `brew upgrade` in which postgresql was updated. I found exactly how to fix my problem from this great post. I was able to get postgres back up and running and even migrated over all my existing databases.
https://coderwall.com/p/ti4amw/how-to-launch-postgresql-after-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and none of the suggested solutions worked for me. After a lot of googling, I did find a solution. This is what worked for me.

First, I had to run this command to start the server and I am guessing set the location of config file.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start && brew services start postgresql
```

Then I ran this command to access postgres

```
psql postgres
```

And at the postgres prompt then I typed "\du" to list the roles

```
postgres=# \du
```

The postgres role was missing so I had to create it with this command

```
CREATE ROLE POSTGRES WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEUSER CREATEROLE REPLICATION BYPASSRLS ;
```

That solved my problem and I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete the `postmaster.pid` file, as this might be inviting data corruption.

Option? Simply `kill` the process (do not use `kill -9`, just an ordinary kill will do).

Then just restart the postgres server and you're good to go!

Here are the steps to achieve that:

1. Locate and open the `postmaster.pid` file (mine is on Mac Sierra)

   `vi ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-10/postmaster.pid`
2. Copy the PID - it's the number on the first line of the `postmaster.pid` file
3. Kill the process with `kill PID`, eg, if my PID is 381, I will do `kill 381`
4. Restart Postres - if using brew, do `brew services start postgresql`.
   Or if using postgresapp, just simply click the `start` button

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall my postgres, great instructions outlined here:
https://medium.com/@zowoodward/effectively-uninstall-and-reinstall-psql-with-homebrew-on-osx-fabbc45c5d9d

Then I had to create postgres user:
`/usr/local/opt/postgres/bin/createuser -s postgres`

This approach will clobber all of your local data so please back up your data if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS I use this:

```
brew info postgres
```

And in output in the most end, I see:

```
...
To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

So I just use this command `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`  and `psql` begin work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was really simple: I had a stale `postmaster.pid` file.

Simply deleting and restarting postgres fixed it for me:

```
rm '/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-10/postmaster.pid'
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time I figured out that there was something wrong with my loop back interface and it wasn't listening on localhost. I passed the following commands to get it working

`sudo ifconfig lo0 down`

then

`sudo ifconfig lo0 up`

Answer (score 0):

A lot many really thorough answers already, but I'll add what I tried and worked for me as it isn't mentioned here so far (and perhaps it internally does what a lot of the answers suggested).

I simply fired up pgAdmin (it took a while to load at first), entered the local db password, and it connected successfully. Then, I returned to the migration command I was trying to run and voila - all is restored in the universe.

All the best!