# Error accessing localhost:3000 with postresql set as the development db in Rails app

Tags: postgresql, sockets, ruby-on-rails-4, tcp, pg

So I have typically used Sqlite3 in Development but wanted to try PG.  Here is the error I got.  Why?

PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

```
$ which psql
$ /usr/local/bin/psql
```

This looks right.

```
**database.yml**

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: timetracker_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: timetracker_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: timetracker_production
  pool: 5
  username: timetracker
  password:
```

Nothing crazy going on here.

```
Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Mostly defaults for new Rails 4 app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure Postgres is actually running. `which postgres` just shows you where it is found, it doesn't mean it's running.

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

You can also do:

```
netstat -an | grep 5432
```

That should report that it's listening on either 0.0.0.0:5432 or 127.0.0.1:5432, I imagine.

It should be listed in the output of those commands. If it's not running, start it.

Next, make sure the user, password, and database listed actually exist.

```
psql DATABASE USERNAME
```

If that lets you in, run `\dt` and see if it tells you any information about your DB. I'd expect it to be blank if it's a new database. If you get a password prompt and it doesn't accept your password, you still need to create the user. You can use this page, http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/, for full instructions on installing and configuring it.

Comment: I have a similar issue, netstat -an | grep 5432 returns nothing, what to do?