# Griddler issue: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailgun, griddler

I'm trying to use Griddler in my Rails 4 app.  The processor appears to be receiving the email (via mailgun) but Griddler isn't saving it.  I'm getting a 500 error with a specific error of **ArgumentError in Griddler::EmailsController#create
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)**.

Here's my processor code:

```
class EmailProcessor
  def self.process(email)
     Post.create!({ body: email.body, email: email.from })
  end
end
```

which came straight from a tutorial at http://sendgrid.com/blog/receiving-email-in-your-rails-app-with-griddler/.

I'm using griddler (1.0.0) and griddler-mailgun (1.0.1).

Any thoughts on why I'd be getting this error would be much appreciated!

Trace (I think... still new to this!):

```
griddler (1.0.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:19:in `initialize'
griddler (1.0.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:19:in `new'
griddler (1.0.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:19:in `process_email'
griddler (1.0.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:4:in `block in create'
griddler (1.0.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:3:in `each'
griddler (1.0.0) app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb:3:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What's your error backtrace?

Comment: @MarekLipka i tried to paste it.  Still new to SO and Rails.  Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered the same issue but with Mandrill and resolved it when I discovered that at some point recently Griddler was updated.

Your EmailProcessor code needs to be updated to the following:

```
    class EmailProcessor

      def initialize(email)
        @email = email
      end

      def process
        Post.create!({ body: @email.body, email: @email.from })
      end

    end
```

I found this out when I re-read the [Configuration Options](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler#configuration-options) on Griddler GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now getting a 500 error again.  Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Have you updated your routes.rb file with `mount_griddler` or one of the other options listed in the installation instructions?

Comment: @grega I think you first need to address the Postgres issues before you try to resolve the issues with Griddler.

[This post might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)