# rails 4 PG::ConnectionBad could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

There are A LOT of similar questions but all slightly different.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Rails 4.2.6 and doing `psql` in the command line returned:

`PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Also got the same in the browser after starting the rails server and attempting to load the root path.

I found that doing `postgres` in the command line didn't work either, returning:

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remove `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` and then restart `postgres`.
On Mac OS you can use `lunchy` for easy restart.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/21920) issue and ran `export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres` in the command line. That allowed me to start postgres with `postgres` (I didn't even know this was necessary - why doesn't Rails do that for you?) and then `rake db:create`, fired up the rails server (in a new tab) and everything worked! I don't know if this is the best solution but thought it was worth sharing.

Comment: Your postgres server must be running. It not responsability of Rails starts the database server

Answer (score 0):

**[Re-posted Answer for Convenience:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420719/737275)**

**Added:**

Manage your installation with `homebrew` if on OSX.

Install Homebrew: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Update it: `brew update`

Install DB: `brew install postgresql`

Load with launchctl: `launchctl load -w /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

**Answer:**

It could be as simple as a stale PID file. It could be failing silently because your computer didn't complete the shutdown process completely which means postgres didn't delete the PID (process id) file. The PID file is used by postgres to make sure only one instance of the server is running at a time. So when it goes to start again, it fails because there is already a PID file which tells postgres that another instance of the server was started (even though it isn't running, it just didn't get to shutdown and delete the PID).

1. To fix it remove/rename the PID file. Find the postgres data directory. On a MAC using homebrew it is `/usr/local/var/postgres/`, other systems it might be `/usr/var/postgres/`.
2. To make sure this is the problem, look at the log file (`server.log`). On the last lines you will see: `FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
   HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 347) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?`
3. If so, `rm postmaster.pid`
4. Restart your server. On a mac using launchctl (with homebrew) the following commands will restart the server.

   `launchctl unload /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

   `launchctl load -w /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Comment: Why copy an answer when you could mark it as a duplicate instead?

Comment: How do you do that?