# rails server with PG:ConnectionBad error on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `rails server` I get the following:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I boot up a browser and navigate to localhost:3000 I get the following error rendered in the browser:

```
Puma caught this error: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 (PG::ConnectionBad)
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `new'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `connect'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:217:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:721:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:765:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:744:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:705:in `acquire_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:501:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:875:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:47:in `block in install_executor_hooks'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_complete_callbacks'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:107:in `complete!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:64:in `ensure in block in run!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:64:in `block in run!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:58:in `tap'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:58:in `run!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:10:in `call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I did look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420719/1013849 but I cannot work out with my PID file is on a Windows 7 machine.

How do I get this up and running?

Comment: check if postgres service is running or try restarting

Comment: I agree with Deepak. Usually this happens when postgresql is not running. In case it is, maybe you might want to look at this. I refer to this when I have common database problems. http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html