# Rake Migrate Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in no way a code developer. Our code developer quit, and I was just given the project. So I am trying to learn code while fixing what ever issues happen. This is the issue that I am currently facing. I need to add new columns into two different tables, I did three separate Active Record Migrations, following the direction. When I tried to update the schema.rb with 
     $ rake db:migrate
I got the following.

```
[pcms -update to 4.4 (master)]$ rake db:migrate
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.2, but has         
dynamically loaded 2.8.0
I, [2017-07-20T08:57:20.436515 #64621]  INFO -- : ** [Raven] Raven 0.13.0 
configured not to send errors.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
     Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

 Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: pcms_development
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: pcms_test
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)

Comment: Can you post your `database.yml` file?

Comment: I've read all of the PG::ConnectionBad thread and nothing on that helped.

Comment: Do you not have a `production` in your `database.yml`? Is your environment set to development on your production server?

Comment: What happens when you try to enter postgres manually?