# How can I connect my ruby app to Heroku postgres database?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, pg, heroku-postgres

I have a ruby app running on heroku, I am trying to connect it to a Heroku postgres database. I have installed the add-on and bundled the 'pg' gem. I tried running

```
PG.connect(dbname:d6td9jdn7irk0u)
```

Only resulting in this:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

**My question is:** how can I get the connection established correctly? should I supply the user/password to the connect() function?

Everything I can find when searching online is about people having a similar problem using ruby on rails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. This question is not a duplicate, I am not using ruby on rails or ActiveRecord. The problem is only occuring on heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku exposes their postgres connection string in `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. So you just `PG.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])`.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku#credentials for details.

Answer (score 1):

solved it, sort of. PG.connect() takes a hash which can include host/port/user/password information. All this information can be retrieved from the heroku cli using:

```
heroku pg:credentials:url database
```

unfortunately, the database credentials aren't permanent. So everytime I deploy I have to make sure the app was successfully deployed.