# rake db:migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10, dbmigrate

I'm still in student mode. Trying to expand my knowledge about deployment. I run into a `rake db:migrate` issue and get the following error message on Windows 10. I added passwords etc but my issue didn't resolve.

> rake aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Please post your pg_hba.conf file and your database.yml file

Comment: Don't forget to take a [tour] as a new User.

Comment: Googling the exception class, which in this case is [PG::ConnectionBad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused), tends to help pretty much every issue.