# Rails : How to configure database.yml for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I'm new on RoR. I build a little app using ActiveAdmin and Devise and I wish to deploy it on Heroku.

When I had push my app on Heroku it run properly but the db seems to be empty ! In effect, my local login dont match when I try to log in my ActiveAdmin administration panel...

In addition, the others db of my app are totaly empty...

I guess that i had not fill the database.yml correctly but I dont find how I'm suppose to do it... :/

**Database.yml :**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I would be grateful if you could help me or direct me to a solution!

Thank you for your attention ! ^^

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> production:
>   <<: *default
>   database: db/production.sqlite3
> ```

You can't use sqlite3 on heroku, because it is filesystem-based and on each restart a new dyno is created, with a completely new filesystem. The old dyno is killed and your sqlite3 data file with it.

Use a client-server DB on heroku, like Postgresql. This is well covered in heroku guides.

Comment: Ty for your answer :)
How I'm suppose to "ask" that to my app ?

Comment: @EmilienLecoffre: that's too big a topic for a small answer and it's out of scope anyway. Also it's very well described in the internets. Start with googling sometihng like "rails use postgresql on heroku"

Comment: I changed :

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/production.pg

And now I'm able to edit the db on the online app but, is it possible to push the content of a local db in a production db ?

Answer (score 0):

These steps is how to push the local database to heroku and to create database

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

1. Get database info

   ```
   heroku pg
   ```

-> Gave me the name of the database
   eg: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN

2. Reset the database on heroku

   ```
   heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN
   ```
3. Look for the name of the local database

   - Opened config/database.yml and found the database
     name for the development environment.
     eg: fashions_development => put the name that the terminal give it to you
4. Run push the local database to Heroku
   Opened config/database.yml and found the database

   ```
   heroku pg:push fashions_development HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN
   ```

Comment: I already done these steps and it work exactly like you. My problem is that my local db informations has not been pushed into my production db :(

Comment: rake db:migrate will only create your database structure

Comment: So how to push both structure AND data ? ^^

Comment: @EmilienLecoffre I just edit the answer its how to push the local data base to heroku in four steps. Try it and let me know if you need any help!

Comment: Ty for this edit :)
In a first time :
I had the "The local psql command could not be located ! For help installing psql, see local-postgresql" error that I have fixed by installing PostgreSQL and update manualy my PATH variable.
Then I get the following error :( $ heroku pg:push db/development.sqlite3 DATABASE_URL
heroku-cli: Pushing db/development.sqlite3 ---> postgresql-flat-56203
pg_dump: [programme d'archivage (db)] la connexion à la base de données « db » a échoué : FATAL:  role "Lecoffre Emilien" does not exist

Comment: According to this link (https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/database/postgresql/solve-the-postgresql-error-psql-fatal-database-root-does-not-exist/), the problem coming from my PostgreSQL Username... :/
I search currently how to modify it

Comment: here they answer my question that i think is similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311186/changing-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-ruby-on-rails