# Getting bad connection error when trying to migrate in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to create a rails api and wanting to migrate the database.  I have started postgresql with the following command `brew services restart postgresql`. The console gave me the following response `` ==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql) ``.  The problem is when I run rails db:migrate I get the following error

```
rails db:migraterails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I did try the following link [PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)

This did not seem to work.

Comment: Are you running on Mojave OSX?

Comment: restart yr terminal and check `brew services list` status of db.

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup the credentials of your database in `config/database.yml` file. you will have config for test, production and development.

change the development block to have username and password for your local DB

```
development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
  timeout: 5000
  host: "localhost"
  database: NAME
```

change the ones that are on uppercase, in database, use the name you want or if you are trying to use an existing one, add that name there. and of course add the username and password that you already created on postgres

if you don't have an user, you can create one like this

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s dev
sudo -u postgres psql
\password dev #here you can type the password you want for this user
\q
```

in this example, we are creating a user named 'dev' so you add dev to the username part and change the password for the one you typed

Comment: Do I add it to the config file like this ```development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
  timeout: 5000
  host: "localhost"
  database: aquastarsbackend_development```

Comment: I am getting the following error ```rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?```

Comment: look at the default block to see what is there, and remove from development the lines that are in default if they are correct, because you are already adding them with `<<: *default` and remember to  change USERNAME and PASSWORD with the ones you created for postgres

Comment: I have not created one in Postgres.  How do I create one in Postgres?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my postgres as when I tried to create a simple rails app I get the same sort of error.

Comment: I edited to add instructions to create a new user on postgres

Comment: I am missing something as this is not doesn't seem straight forward.