# Rails 7 `rake db:migrate` PG::ConnectionBad Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails 7 app with a previously-functioning Postgres database, but now suddenly when I try and run a simple `rake db:migrate` I'm getting this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

I have the following `database.yml`, which is copied directly from another app which can still `rake db:whatever` just fine:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: MHV_2023_development
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  <<: *default
  database: MHV_2023_test
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

production:
  <<: *default
  database: MHV_2023_production
  username: mhv_2023
  password: <%= ENV["MHV_2023_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

I can successfully login with `$psql -U postgres` and have done the `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';` thing and the passwords listed in `database.yml` are correct.

This whole issue came when I was attempting to get pgsync to work, if that makes any difference.

Has anyone run up against this issue?  I've looked at other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621176/getting-bad-connection-error-when-trying-to-migrate-in-rails), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690162/rails-postgres-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied).  I've restarted postgres with Homebrew....any ideas?

EDIT:  When I run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config` on my `rails c` here's the result:

```
@configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :database=>"mhv_2023_development", :username=>"postgres", :password=>"postgres", :host=>"localhost", :port=>5432},
 @env_name="development",
 @name="primary">
```

Comment: Are you somehow running rails in the production env on your dev machine?

Comment: Show the output of this from your rails console: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config`

Comment: @smathy Excellent tool to know about!  I added the results to the OP.

Comment: Did you happen to reinstall PG or maybe install this project on a new machine since you last had it working vs the present?

Comment: Ok so that's all what's expected, I'm guessing you made some `pg_hba.conf` changes when trying to get `pgsync` to work and those are messing things up. In your search I would focus on the `fe_sendauth` thing, I've not seen that specific string in a pg connection error before; quite a few results ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17996957/152786) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/526170/psql-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied) eg) come up searching for that.

Comment: It turned out it was trying to run the production environment even through localhost.  Once I got it running development it worked!  Thanks @smathy