# Locating new postgres database (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a mistake today by following this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685657/10104165. As a result I lost  a database with 104 tables. I managed to retrieve the table from Heroku when the app is running as well.

I followed these steps:

```
$ heroku pg:backups:capture
```

then :

```
$ heroku pg:backups:download
```

and finally:

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost  -d project4_development latest.dump
```

I got all the data back, but for some reason the data_source in my rubymine window says that project4_development does not exist. A part from a few issues, the app seems to be running a usual.

How can I find out where (which database) are the data currently displayed coming from ?

Comment: Which framework is your app server running from?
Perhaps from database config files

Or since you have mentioned heroku, heroku has environment variable `DATABASE_URL` that gives which database your app server is connecting to.

Comment: By `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost  -d project4_development latest.dump` you are trying to dump latest.dump into your localhost.
And in your local there is no database that is named `project4_development`

Comment: Ok, so I should create another database first before running that command ? In that case, where are the data that I am currently seeing coming from ?

Comment: You can fire up the console and run `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` to see the database information

Comment: If you want to restore your local db from heroku jsut do:  heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL project4_development --app APPNAMEHERE

Comment: All good guys, I managed to plug the new data source to rubymine.  Thank yOU!