# PG::ConnectionBad could not connect to server - heroku local rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-postgres

I was trying to run `heroku local` or `heroku local web` and everything was working fine. After importing the data from my heroku remote to my local environment, it started to throw me the following error:
[image]

After searching for the solution in some places, I tried restarting the postgresql service with `brew services restart postgresql` and it started normally but I kept receiving the error. I also tried to delete the `postmaster.pid` as suggested on this SO post [PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused) but didn't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finding the solution was easier than I thought.

On this same post ([PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)) it suggested to check the logs before deleting the file and I did even that I haven't finding the file to be deleted.

When I checked the logs, I came across the following:
[image]

So, I checked the heroku's Postgres version and it uses the 12 as default but `brew` uses the latest, which is the 13th.

To sum up, I did a dump from a Postgre v12 to Postgre v13 and this is incompatible, so I'm going to downgrade my local Postgres to work with my data as expected.

To do that, I did the following:

`brew uninstall postgres` - to remove v13

`brew install postgresql@12` - to install a specific version

`brew services start postgresql@12` - to start the new version

Cool fact, I didn't need to restore or modify the data because it wasn't deleted even uninstalling the Postgresql.